# Android Intent Database

Tags: android, database, android-intent

Is there an Intent-database where one can search for applications that publish common services? For example I could have an idea about a filter that could be applyed to photos in a photo-application, but under what intent should I publish my filter so that other applications can find it and use it?

So the question is if there are a more or less standard database for intents and when to use them? And then I don't only mean the android intents, although a list of them would be nice too :-)

Thanks in advance
Roland

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. [OpenIntents](http://www.openintents.org/en/) is one registry and the [google apps](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) have their own listing.