# General purpose Android Intent Database / Library

Tags: android, android-intent

I used to have a look at [openintents.org](http://openintents.org) to find information about Intents in general. I also noticed here that questions about how to send an email, how to take a photo, ... were getting asked on a regular basis.

I also found this question: [Android Intent Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5290443/android-intent-database), which does not yet have an answer.

Hence I have compiled my current utility functions into a library and put it on Git: [Android Intents](https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-intents)

Which Intents do you keep using again and again? Which are the general purpose intents one could expect to find in such a library?

I start answering my own question by putting the list of what I so far have been required to used in various projects (and I have provided in the library):

- Send email
- Send SMS
- Dial / call phone number
- Open URL in browser
- Play video
- Take photo
- Pick photo from gallery
- Open a chooser to share a text
- Show an address in a map application

PS: maybe this question could/should be turned into a community wiki later on?

Comment: Looks cool.  Will keep an eye on this.

Comment: @Booger Will be even cooler if you could add some intents to that list (and way-way cooler if you have the corresponding code ;) )

Answer (score -1):

Intent is an abstract operation to be performed, even you can [define your own intent](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/) and make some intent filters in your other application.

Defining intent filter in other app tells that if user calls for this intent your app can handle it. For example you've wrote "Show an address in Google Maps" - it's not exactly accurate, the intent is to show given coordinates on **map** - and not only **google map**, if you have other map provider (yandex {in Russia} for example) - after calling "map" intent system will ask you where do you want to show your coordinates - google or yandex.

I think all definitions of basic intents [you can find here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Also even default intents can have parameters - for example when you taking photo from camera\gallery you can ask your system to crop this picture with given size\ratio.

As i see the best way to share this expiriance is smth like wiki with examples (even with creating your own custom intent). People often looking for manuals how to perform some actions - some text with explanation i think will be better than library.

Comment: I got to disagree on that, sorry. I noticed that more or less every (professional) developer ends-up writing his own wrappers to build common intents such as send email (kind of thing you can do in multiple places even within a single app. This lib would serve the same purpose as e.g. Guava or Apache Commons: provide functions to construct your intents to avoid repeating yourself. The lib returns  intents, so you are always free to add the extras you want. Furthermore, such a library could detect for instance if you are running a kindle or a google device and build the map intent accordingly.

Comment: Additionally, the link you provide is only a starting point. Else you would not see here so many questions about how to properly build the intent to take a picture or to send an email. Those extras to pass are sometimes not well documented or simply not the kind of code you'd want to worry about if you had a simple function to build the intent for you (i.e. focus on your app code, not on code to call other apps).

Comment: I don't tell that such description with maybe sample codes are useless - i only want to say if i want for example email intent, i will copy\paste the only code\wrapper that do what i need - i don't want to add the whole library and the code i don't need to execute.

Comment: As i've already said: "As i see the best way to share this expiriance is smth like wiki with examples" - your code is usefull to reuse it in many projects, but i will prefer to store this classes as templates and copy only neccessary classes in each project.

Comment: As i see this samples as library will be usefull if you create you own usefull wildly use APIs, like openintents did. For example you cal find calc api here http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable so developers can build apps to filter this intent and other phones with openintents can use this API

Comment: Proguard will strip unused code anyway, so there is no point in getting scared about the library size. I bet you don't use Apache Commons or Guava either. Both are rather large and indeed, they solve problems that can be copy/pasted in a small function most of the time. (e.g. IoUtils.closeQuietly or Objects.isNullOrEmpty). However, why keeping pasting such code in projects while you could get it for free and tested by including the library. Anyway, my question was about what to include in such a library rather than is such a library useful.

Comment: Maybe you are right, good luck with library. BTW the usefull thing is "share intent"